# Laravel 4.2 URI based configuration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on a project which has multiple URL's, and each URL need a custom configuration. It does not have to be in it's own configuration file, but would be a nice to have (for a clear overview of project structure).

At the moment I have the following in my custom configuration file, which works - but is IMO not the best place to put this.

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
switch($domain)
{
    case 'domain':
        $var = 'foo';
        break;
    case 'otherdomain':
        $var = 'bar';
        break;
}
```

I've tried adding the same code to filters, in App::before function (but instead of $var =, I do:)

```
Config::set('var','foo')
```

Unfortunately, this does not give me the desired effect, when I do it like this - I cannot access Config::get('var') in my configuration file to make the switch between the different variables I need per URL.

I'm pretty sure there should be a better way to handle this than my "I'll add it to config file". Can anybody point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use environments for this. Just create directories under `app/config` like:

```
config
-- domain
-- otherdomain
```

And place a file in them. Let's say `app.php`. In there you return an array of config values:

```
return array(
    'foo' => 'bar'
);
```

And finally, in `bootstrap/start.php`, change the `detectEnvironment` call to this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this - didn't cross my mind as I had DEV / TEST / PRODUCTION in mind.